# Are there examples of standardized ways to run a business, such as a restaurant?

Tags: business, standards

I was wondering if there is some kind of industry-standard set of procedures for anything, like running a restaurant or a bar.

If you imagine someone running a beergarden, they are independently managing all aspects, like buying and shipping in drinks, kegs of beer, getting gas for the tap replaced, the electricity bill and rent, cleaning, maintaining dishwashers and the electronic payment system, incidents of theft on the premises, food hygiene and safety, and so on.

Is there some way to try to implement a highly standardized procedure to run such a business so that you would not have to learn everything from scratch on your own, to varying levels of success, but maybe a company or organization supplies you with everything you need to run the actual business - not just supplies and equipment, but everything including management policy, employee management systems like what software system you would use, what the employment contract and rights will be, salaries and promotion guidelines; everything. Like, if Starbucks or Chipotle have some kind of standardized business model they can replicate from place to place - or also retail outlets like Nike, Apple, American Apparel - or also hotels like the Four Seasons or Marriott - unless there is a known franchise that provides the product you already had in mind, is there some fallback to at least adopt from or borrow as many standardized components as possible? Like, you could just use some specific software that manages all aspects of employment so you have automatically a really good system, without needing to be able to build one yourself? You just follow along with the app. And the same for everything else, some standard food provider/caterer, some standard business consultancy / pricing agency, or something?

Comment: Many people working for big companies have quit and opened their own consulting firm, using all their experience to build (and sell!) those procedures. But your question is very broad and (to me) not that clear.

Comment: Agree with VTC-ing - "How do I run a business" is not really a Workplace question per se.

Comment: Many people learn the essentials of these skills by working for someone else in that profession and seeing how they do it before starting their own business -- an unofficial apprenticeship, essentially.

Answer (score 6):

You are describing a franchise system. Many of those chains you mention (Coffee, fast food) have a program where you invest your money and they help you find a location, and then sell you all the supplies and the procedures.  Those companies also run training programs for managers to learn how to run the business.

Many hotel chains work the same way. They allow investors to own one or more locations. The property is then integrated into the reservation system, and has access to the corporate branded stuff. Sometimes the building is constructed from scratch so it looks like the corporate property. This goes beyond colors and includes architectural elements. Sometimes an existing location switches chains and looks out of place because it is missing some of the architectural features.

I assume it also works for other business in malls and shopping centers.

If somebody doesn't want to own one of these properties the corporations also run training programs to develop managers.

Comment: Of course in a franchise you pay for the advantages of using the brand name, getting the training, benefiting from the advertising, etc... and may have to buy essential supplies from the parent company, which may be more expensive than non-branded equivalents. It's a trade-off like any other business decision.